# CI/CD pipeline for AWS Glue

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, aws-codepipeline

I am fairly a new user of AWS Glue, which is one of new AWS managed services to orchestrate batch job workflows with ease.

- I have 3 different AWS IAM account (Dev, Test, Prod). Separate
  login for each account.
- Glue, Scala Jobs are version controlled in my
  Github repository.
- I want to build a CI/CD pipeline to automate the
  Test, Build and deployment of my Glue job as I commit and push in my Github repository.

I went through number of blogs and article describing CI/CD best practices. I found a good article (specifically on CI/CD in Data Pipeline workflows) on AWS Blog [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/implement-continuous-integration-and-delivery-of-serverless-aws-glue-etl-applications-using-aws-developer-tools/). It is quite simple and has details of building CodePipeline using CodeCommit & AWS Cloudformation. But all the phases of CI/CD initiate and ends in the same AWS IAM account.

I have two questions:

1. Is separating Dev, Test and Prod account (different IAM) for building and managing
   Data Pipelines/ Data warehouse, a good practice?
2. If yes, how would I design CI/CD pipeline using 3 different IAM account?

Any suggestion on best practices to design CI/CD pipeline for AWS-Glue ?

Comment: Are you talking about something like this https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/aws-building-a-secure-cross-account-continuous-delivery-pipeline/  ?

Comment: Yes !! Thanks for the resource. Saved the day.

Comment: I am glad that the provided information was helpful. I have posted the answer now.Please mark it as answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please refer to [this](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/aws-building-a-secure-cross-account-continuous-delivery-pipeline/) which explains in detail on setting up a CI/CD pipeline across multiple accounts in a secured manner.

*Is separating Dev, Test and Prod account (different IAM) for building and managing Data Pipelines/ Data warehouse, a good practice?*

> > Yes it is a good practice.

*If yes, how would I design CI/CD pipeline using 3 different IAM account?*

> > Please refer to the shared link

Comment: I am still working on best practices for AWS Glue job deployment with CI/CD (CodePipeline). I will keep posting. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

*Is separating Dev, Test and Prod account (different IAM) for building and managing Data Pipelines/ Data warehouse, a good practice?*

Yes, separating environments in different AWS accounts is a good practice, it's recommended security practice as well.

*If yes, how would I design CI/CD pipeline using 3 different IAM account?*

[Here](https://medium.com/@mishra.anoop6/aws-codepipeline-with-a-cross-account-codecommit-repository-904f037b235c) is a blog which defines how you can configure resources in different AWS accounts and securely communicate with them.